# Network UNCLAIMED ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04

My Ethernet stoped work.
I was checking "lash -c network and get network UNCLAIMED.

I download from Realtek Website the driver I need, and tried to install it. but I get
"check old driver and unload it"
How can I check and upload an old driver?

result of lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3

...
*
~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 16)  Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Onboard Ethernet [1458:e000]
```

result of : sudo modprobe r8169

~$ sudo modprobe r8169
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-31-generic

when I tried this command lsmod | grep r816
I didnt get anything

results t of :
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status

...
dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-31-generic' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files

...

I don't have any network there to make updates.

Maybe someone have another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: Hi I just added .
Thanks

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo modprobe r8169` and: `lsmod | grep r816` Please edit to show the result.

Comment: Very interesting! How about: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: Just added . Thanks